# HTML file input not working

Tags: php, html

I am making a social media website for a final project in a class. In this page I am trying to allow a user to insert and image into a wall post. I have the code for the html form which takes in the file and it works perfectly when it is on its own but when I try to put it into my code the $_FILES array in php is always empty. I already made sure that the max post size and max input size in the php.ini file are large enough but I really don't know what else to do at this point I tried every suggestion on every other post of stackoverflow. This is my form for the input

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="myFile">

  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submitForm" />

</form>
```

here is the php code that processes the form

```
if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {


print_r($_FILES);
```

}

Like I said the form and php code to process it work fine if I put them in their own file but when I put it in the file I actually want to use it never works. Here is the entire file. I suspect there is some other code making it break

```
        <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {


        print_r($_FILES);


    }

    session_start();
    include "../includes/dbConnection.php";
    $dbConn = getDatabaseConnection("book_face");


    //if user not signed in go to login
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('Location: signin.php');
    }
    //print_r($_FILES);



    function getSignedInUser($username){
        global $dbConn;
        $namedParameters = array();
        $namedParameters[':username'] = $username;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user
                WHERE username = :username";
        $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($namedParameters);
        $record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $record;
    }

    //determines if signed in user is friends with this user
    function isFriends($signedInId, $userId){
        global $dbConn;
        $namedParameters = array();
        $namedParameters[':user1'] = $signedInId;
        $namedParameters['user2'] = $userId;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends
                WHERE user1 = :user2
                AND user2 = :user1";
        $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($namedParameters);
        $record = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (empty($record)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //gets records of the user from the given id
    function getProfileInfo($id){
        global $dbConn;

        $namedParameters = array();
        $namedParameters[':id'] = $id;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user
                WHERE id = :id";
        $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($namedParameters);
        $record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $record;
    }



    //gets the user friends ti display in friends div
    function getUsersFriends($id){
        global $dbConn;
        $namedParameters = array();
        $namedParameters[':id'] = $id;
        /*
        $sql = "SELECT *, user.id FROM friends
        JOIN user ON user.id = friends.user2 OR user.id = friends.user1 
        WHERE user1 = :id OR user2 = :id";
        */
        $sql = "SELECT *, user.id FROM user
                JOIN friends ON friends.user1 = user.id OR friends.user2 = user.id
                WHERE friends.user1 = user.id OR friends.user2 = user.id";

        $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($namedParameters);
        $records = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //deleteDuplicates($records);
        $counter = 0;
        $unique = array();
        foreach($records as $record){
            //print_r($record);
            //echo $record['id'];
            if (array_search($record['id'],$unique) == false && $record['id'] != $id && ($record['user1'] == $id || $record['user2'] == $id)){
                //echo $record['id'];
                //echo "true";

                $unique[] = $record['id'];
            }
        }
        $unique = array_unique($unique);
        //print_r($unique);
        echo "<h3 style='text-align:center'>Friends:</h3>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($unique);$i++){

            $record = getProfileInfo($unique[$i]);
            //print_r($record);
            echo "<div  class='searchResult' id='".$record.['id']."' onclick='getResultId(".$record['id'].")'>";
                    //echo "<span>" . $record['firstName'] . " " . $record['lastName'] . " " . $record['username'] . "</span>";
                    echo "<img class='profilePic' src='img/".$record['avatar'] . "'>";
                    echo "<p>";
                    echo "Name: " . $record['firstName'] . " " . $record['lastName'] . "</br>";
                    echo "Username: " . $record['username'] . "</br>";
                    echo "Lives in: " . $record['state'] . "</br>";
                    echo "<a href='profile.php?id=".$record['id']."'>View Profile</a>";
                    echo "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
        }
    }

    $signedInUser = getSignedInUser($_SESSION['username']);
    $profileId = $_GET['id']; //id of curren users profile
    $profileRecords = getProfileInfo($profileId); //records of current profile


    //displas record info of inpued user
    function displayProfileInfo($record){
        global $signedInUser;
        global $profileRecords;


        echo "<img style='margin:0 auto' class='profileAvatar' src='img/".$record['avatar'] . "'></br>";
        echo "<div style='margin:0 auto;margin:10px;text-align:center;background-color:white;border:2px solid black'>";
        echo "<h3 id='profileName' style='text-align:center'>".$record['firstName']. " " . $record['lastName']. "</h3>";
        echo "<h3 id='profileName' style='text-align:center'>Username: ".$record['username']. "</h3>";
        echo "<h3 id='profileName' style='text-align:center'>Lives in: ".$record['state']. "</h3>";
        echo "<h3 id='profileName' style='text-align:center'>".$record['age']. " years old" .  "</h3>";
        echo "<h3 id='profileName' style='text-align:center'>Gender: ".$record['gender'] .  "</h3>";
        echo "</div>";
        if (!isFriends($signedInUser['id'],$record['id']) && $signedInUser['id'] != $profileRecords['id']){
            echo "<button type='button' style='margin:0 auto;text-align:center;margin-left:200px' class='btn btn-default' id='addFriend' onclick='var user1 = ".json_encode($signedInUser['id']).";var user2 = ".json_encode($record['id']).";addFriend(user1,user2);'>Add Friend</button>";
        }else{
            echo "<button type='button' style='margin:0 auto;text-align:center;margin-left:200px' class='btn btn-default' id='removeFriend' onclick='var user1 = ".json_encode($signedInUser['id']).";var user2 = ".json_encode($record['id']).";removeFriend(user1,user2);'>Remove Friend</button>";
        }

    }



    function getUserPosts($id){



        global $dbConn;
        global $signedInUser;
        global $profileRecords;
        $namedParameters = array();
        $namedParameters[':id'] = $id;

        if ($id == $signedInUser['id']){
            /*
            echo "<div style='width:90%;height:10%'>";
                echo "<h3 style='text-align:center'>Create new post</h3>";
                //echo "<textarea id='postContent' name='postContent'>What's on your mind?</textarea>";
            echo "</div>";
            */
            echo "<html><html>";
            echo "<div id='theNewPost' class='post'>";
                echo "<div style='float:right' class='btn-group' role='group'>";
                  //echo "<button id='textPost' type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='changePost(1)'>Text Post</button>";
                  //echo "<button id='imagePost' type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='changePost(0)'>Image Post</button>";
            echo "</div>";
                echo "<h3 style='text-align:justify;margin-left:50px'>Create new post</h3>";

                echo "<textarea id='postContent' name='postContent'>What's on your mind?</textarea>";
                echo "<button type='button' style='float:right;margin-right:100px;margin-top:20px' class='btn btn-default' id='newPostBtn' onclick='var id=".json_encode($signedInUser['id']).";addPost(id);'>Post</button>";
                echo "<span id='postError' class='error' style='clear:both'></span>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM post
        WHERE authorId = :id";

        $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($namedParameters);
        $records = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($records as $record){
            echo "<div class='homePostSearchResult'>";
                echo "<img src='img/".$profileRecords['avatar']."' />";
                echo "<p style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px'>".$record['content']."</p>";
                echo "<button type='button' style='float:right;margin-right:50px' class='glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right' id='".$record['id']."' value='".$record['likes']."'onclick='var id=".json_encode($record['id']).";likePost(id)'> Likes: ".$record['likes']."</button>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }



    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> </title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/Project2.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
            <script>
                /*
                function changePost(type){
                    alert(type);
                    if (type == 0){
                        $("#postContent").css("display","none");
                        $("#imgUploadForm").css("display","block");
                        $("#file").css("display","block");
                        $("#selectImgSpan").css("display","block");
                        $("#fileSubmit").css("display","block");
                    }else{
                        $("#postContent").css("display","block");
                        $("#imgUploadForm").css("display","none");
                        $("#file").css("display","none");
                        $("#selectImgSpan").css("display","none");
                        $("#fileSubmit").css("display","none");
                    }

                }*/
                function signOut(){
                    window.location="signin.php";
                }

                function removeFriend(user1,user2){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "removeFriend.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { "user1": user1, "user2": user2 },
                        success: function(data,status) {
                                alert(data);
                                window.location.reload();
                          },
                          complete: function(data,status) { //optional, used for debugging purposes
                              //alert(status);
                          }
                    });
                }

                function likePost(id){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "likePost.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { "id":id, "likes":$("#" + id).val() },
                        success: function(data,status) {

                                $("#" + id).val(parseInt($("#" + id).val()) + 1);
                                $("#" + id).html(" Likes: " + $("#" + id).val());
                          },
                          complete: function(data,status) { //optional, used for debugging purposes
                              //alert(status);
                          }
                    });
                }

                function addFriend(user1, user2){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "addFriend.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { "user1": user2, "user2": user1 },
                        success: function(data,status) {
                                alert(data);
                                window.location.reload();
                          },
                          complete: function(data,status) { //optional, used for debugging purposes
                              //alert(status);
                          }
                    });
                }

                function addPost(id){
                    alert(id);
                    alert($('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name)
                    if (validatePost()){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "addPost.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { "postContent": $("#postContent").val(), "id": id },
                            success: function(data,status) {
                                    alert("Successfully posted!");
                                    window.location.reload();
                              },
                              complete: function(data,status) { //optional, used for debugging purposes
                                  //alert(status);
                              }
                        });
                    }else{
                        alert("Invalid Post");
                    }
                }

                function validatePost(){
                    var isValid = true;
                    $("#postError").html("");

                    if ($("#postContent").val().trim().length == 0){
                        isValid = false;
                        $("#postError").html("Post cannot be blank");
                    }
                    if ($("#postContent").val().trim().length > 40){
                        isValid = false;
                        $("#postError").html("Post cannot exceed 40 characters");
                    }

                    return isValid;
                }



                $(document).ready( function(){ 
                $("#friends").css("display","block");
                 $("#postContent").change( function(){  
                     validatePost();
                 } );//username changes
                });

            </script>
        <nav>
                <form id="homeSearch" method="post">
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                        echo"<p style=';font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;color:white' class='navbar-text navbar-right'>Signed in as <a style='color:orange' href='profile.php?id=".$signedInUser['id']."'' class='navbar-link'>".$signedInUser['username']."</a></p>";
                    }

                    ?>
                    <span id="bookFace">BookFace</span>



                    <div style="float:right" class="dropdown">

                  <button style="margin-top:0;margin-left:0" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Navigate
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == "ZMark"){
                            echo "<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin Page</a></li>";
                            echo "<li><a href='statistics.php'>Statistics</a></li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                            echo "<li><a href='profile.php?id=".$profileRecords['id']."'>Profile</a></li>";
                            echo "<li role='separator' class='divider'></li>";
                            echo "<li><a href='signin.php'>Sign Out</a></li>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<li><a href='signin.php'>Sign In</a></li>";
                            echo "<li><a href='signup.html'>Sign Up</a></li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                  </ul>
                </div>





            </nav>
        </head>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          Select image to upload:
          <input type="file" name="myFile">

          <input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submitForm" />

        </form>

        <body style="background-color:#d7dde5">
            <div id="profileInfo">
                <?php

                    displayProfileInfo($profileRecords);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="friends">

                <?php
                    getUsersFriends($profileRecords['id']);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id= "friendPosts">
                <?php
                    getUserPosts($profileRecords['id']);

                ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    ?>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there that isn't relevant to the question. Can you trim this down to the minimum that reproduces the problem? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sending the form to your `PHP` page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. Are you asking if the form sends the data to another php file to process? If thats what you meant then no the form doesnt have an action or onsubmit function.

Answer (score 0):

there is no action in your  tag?
you can try this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your_action.php">

//your form

</form>
```

Comment: The `action` attribute isn't strictly required. If it's omitted, the form posts to the current URL, unless otherwise overridden. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attributes-for-form-submission